# multiple authentication manager in spring security

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security

I'm new at spring security. I want to have two different login forms for two different type of users. I have a package called /admin which is contained my main project for system users and /portal for other users./portal users will work on their tenant and won't know anything about /admin and vice versa.Each user group has its own database too.
In spring-security.xml I defined two authentication managers,but when I login from both login forms it goes to 'AuthenticatingManager' but as I mentioned in xml file, for /portal users it should goes to PortalAuthenticatingManager. what shall I do? or what did I miss?

```
<security:http use-expressions="true" pattern="/portal/**" authentication-manager-ref="portalAuthMgr"  access-denied-page="/unauthorized.jsp">
    <form-login login-page="/plLogin.jsp"  default-target-url="/portal/portal"  />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/plLogin.jsp" access="permitAll"/>
<security:intercept-url pattern="/portal/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_PORTAL')" />
</security:http>
<security:http  authentication-manager-ref="adminAuthMgr" access-denied-page="/unauthorized.jsp">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
<security:form-login login-page="/login.jsp"  authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager id="adminAuthMgr">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="produxAuthenticationProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>
<security:authentication-manager alias="portalAuthMgr">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="portalAuthenticationProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="produxAuthenticationProvider" class="com.spring.AuthenticatingManager">
</beans:bean>
 <beans:bean id="portalAuthenticationProvider" class="com.spring.PortalAuthenticatingManager">
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: You need to rework the indentation :|

Answer (score 1):

Your "portal" login form needs to post to a URL beginning with `/portal/**`, otherwise the login request will be handled by the second filter chain. It should work if you use`/portal/j_spring_security_check`

Note that you can also use the `login-processing-url` attribute on `form-login` element to control which URL the filter responds to. Using different URLs for each would avoid the issue where one accidentally processes a request meant for the other.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I did as you mentioned but now after trying to login from plLogin it doesn't fire neither 'AuthenticatingManager' or 'PortalAuthenticatingManager'. I did also add login-processing-url="/portal/**" but it didn't work.When I change form action attribute in portal login form to action="/portal/j_spring_security_check", it just goes to 'http://localhost:8083/portal/j_spring_security_check' with a blank content and not fire my 'PortalAuthenticatingManager' class.